# Refused to frame 'https://www.facebook.com/' because an ancestor violates the Content Security Policy : "frame-ancestors https://www.facebook.com"

Tags: reactjs, facebook, shopify

I've implemented the facebook sdk using npm package "react-messenger-customer-chat", which takes pageid and appid as props. I am injecting this code into shopify store (using iframe) using shopify scrpittags api. I've also whitelisted the shopify store domain on my facebook page, still getting this error. Can you please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: https://medium.com/@vishuwayachal/facebook-customer-chat-plugin-refused-to-display-frame-ancestors-https-www-facebook-com-53c464e06c0f

Answer (score 0):

Check if your page is publicly visible.